# Why do I have to put the condition twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I don't really have a problem, but I don't understand the solution.

On the project view (show), I check if the viewer is connected. If not, I render a banner at a certain position depending on the number of offers.

**Offers view (rendered within the project view):**

```
- @offers.each_with_index do |offer, index|

   - if !user_signed_in? && (@project.published? || @project.pending_attribution?)
      - if cta_banner_position(@offers, index)
         = render 'projects/cta_banner_guest_presta.html.haml'
```

**cta_banner_position helper:**

```
def cta_banner_position(offer, index)
   index == 2 || (offer.size == 2 && index == 1) || (offer.size == 1 && index == 0)
end
```

**The rendered banner:**

```
.row
   .col-md-12
      .project-cta.p-5.mb-2.text-center
         %h5
            %strong
               blabla
          %p.text-muted blabla
          %p.m-0
             = link_to "Send a quote", "", class: "btn btn-primary px-3", data: { toggle: 'modal', target: '#modal-sign' }, onclick: "ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'Clic', 'Projects signup inoffers');", tabindex: -1
```

I use each_with_index to obtain the position and set the banner, this works but, if I'm connected, I can see the banner (despite the !user_signed_in condition) ONLY if there no offer.

I don't understand why I have the rendered banner while I'm connected.
To solve this problem, I also must add " *- if !user_signed_in?* " at the top of the banner file. When I do it, the banner stops showing if I'm signed in.

Could anyone explain to me why he ignores the first condition, and especially why only when there is no offer?

Comment: you might have `= render 'projects/cta_banner_guest_presta.html.haml'` somewhere else

Comment: hi @fl00r, this is the only one (not the same mistake twice haha)

Comment: it's haml, then you might have indentation problems. In your question, the indentation is not valid for example. You have an extra tab before render.

Comment: the indentation is also right, I had to do it with whitespace in the post so it's a bit different from my code (but all is good, I checked before to ask)

Comment: Again. That's invalid haml in your question.

Comment: @floor i changed this, but it's not the problem with the banner

Comment: ok, now your code is valid and doesn't have any issues, so the problem is somewhere else. Double check if you render `projects/cta_banner_guest_presta.html.haml` somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper is doing nothing. You're just returning nil if that condition is met (or if it isn't). Instead, just return that long Boolean logic and have an `- if cta_banner_position(@offers, index)`. This will fix the indentation issue that @fl00r mentioned, since there was nothing for your cta banner to be nested under previously.

I don't think the helper was even being called before, usually need a - in front of Ruby for it to execute in haml

Comment: I had this before, you're right, I returned to this solution. But it's not the problem, the banner still here if i'm connected and there is no offers

Comment: @escanxr " the banner still here if i'm connected and there is no offers" - judging from the code you posted so far in this question, this seems to be impossible. I'm afraid we'll need some kind of [mcve] (to even see the problem)